# Restoring SQL Server database from backup

Tags: sql-server, database

I've been trying to restore my DB from back up by I keep getting errors

> RESTORE cannot process database 'Users' because it is in use by this session. It is recommended that the master database be used when performing this operation. RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

I do understand that I have to use another database such as the master, but how am I able to change the default database without using SQL Server Configuration Manager?

Comment: or the sql server management studio

Comment: `use master ; then restore command` wont this work for you

Comment: This question doesn't appear to have anything to do with asp.net. Please remove the tag or add details relevant to asp.net.

Comment: I've tried user master and the restore, it does not work..

Comment: You should be able to specify a database to connect to when you open the connection. For example, the -d switch on sqlcmd.